# Firefox can't establish a connection to socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firefox, socket.io

Firefox throws the following error:

```
"Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=n_QyMdXsrpQhtPuxAAAH."
```

about 20 seconds after the socket connects.  On the server side, the connection is being registered as expected and no disconnections are being logged.  Strangely, the firefox client is still able to emit messages that are being received on chrome clients.  The code that's throwing the error is from node module engine.io-client/lib/transports/websocket.js in the SSL options section:

```
try {
  this.ws = this.usingBrowserWebSocket ? (protocols ? new WebSocket(uri, protocols) : new WebSocket(uri)) : new WebSocket(uri, protocols, opts);
} catch (err) {
  return this.emit('error', err);
}
```

Lastly, requests are being proxied from 3000 to 3001 by react.